# Slightly better way of removing new lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a text/string that contains multiple newlines. Like in the example below :

```
"This is a test message     : \n \n\n  \n    \n    \n    \n    \n  \n   \n    \n      \n         \n      \n      \n        \n          \n          \n            \n   

        "
```

I can gsub all `\n` with space and remove them all. How can I do the following :

- If I see that there is more than two `\n`, leave only two newlines in the text?

Comment: Do you mean, allow only two subsequent newlines with nothing between them? so `\n \n\n \n` would be fine, but `\n\n\n \n` would be changed to `\n\n \n`? Or would all new lines be removed leaving only two? If that's the case, *which* two? Please give us an example of the output you'd expect, given your test message as input. What about leading new lines? What about new lines in the middle of the text? Will the new lines always be trailing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all but the first two newlines you can use the block passed to `gsub`:

```
hits = 0
text.gsub(/\n/) { (hits = hits + 1) > 2 ? '' : "\n" }
# => "This is a test message     : \n \n                                                                                                         "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace any sequences of three or more newlines with nothing in between, by using the following regex (assuming `s` 
contains your string):

```
s.gsub /\n\n+/, "\n\n"
```

If you want to allow any amount of interleaving space characters between the newlines and remove that as well, better use:

```
s.gsub /\n *(\n *)+/, "\n\n"
```